# как с помощью discord.py сделать список команд при наборе сообщения как в juniperbot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

[image: подсказки в jupiterbot]

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('testing')

@bot.command()
async def test1(ctx):
    await ctx.send('testing1')


bot.run('token')
```

[image: деловой кот]

Answer (score 2):

Боты не могут изменять данный список подсказок, так как это команды *дискорда*, а не бота. Они выполняются вашим клиентом на вашей стороне, перед отправкой сообщения. Боты могут "мимикрировать" под эти подсказки путём использования префикса `/`, но это скорее сделает команды бота недоступными на клиентах с данными командами.

Для форматирования помощи по команде `[p]help` в discord.py у конструктора `commands.Bot` существует аргумент [`help_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.help_command), который принимает объект класса [HelpCommand](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand):

```py
class MyHelp(commands.HelpCommand):
    """My very own help formatter"""

    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
        """Send this on [p]help without arguments"""
        channel = self.get_destination()
        await channel.send("Here is your help, enjoy!")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&', help_command=MyHelp())
```

Comment: это теперь можно сделать